# Timthumb.php: internal image not found

Tags: thumbnails

I'm getting the following error when using the Timthumb.php script from (http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/):

**The following error(s) occured:
Could not find the internal image you specified.
Query String : src=http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/templatename/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/mainimage.jpg
TimThumb version : 2.8.10**

I'm not sure whats going on, the internal image does exist, when I try resizing an external image (http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2340/2089504883_863fb11b0a_z.jpg&h=200&w=120), the script works with no issues.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Check out this possible solution for someone who was having a similar problem:
http://git.atp.usp.br/wordpress.git/commitdiff/5a78fe0083321da8d71f97be66dafda204f174e9?hp=fd0754f3b884c30a3cd538651314db43b52674e7

  It has to do with the image when delivered via the web server not being delivered from the same address as it is stored locally.

Comment: Thanks, I came across this solution already and tried it out but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is timthumb.php file with problem fixed by someone here:
http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/issues/detail?id=363
and here:
http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/issues/detail?id=315